# Show parents element's item

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, toggle, show-hide

Lets say we have something like:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="box">
          <a class="more" href="#more"/>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden">
          stuff
      </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="box">
          <a class="more" href="#more"/>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden">
          stuff
      </div>  
  </div>
```

So when you click on the `more link` it `toggles` the `hidden class`. but not both hidden classes.

I tried to edit some stuff with `$(this)` but nothing.

Just started jquery/js so not the best with it.

This is what I have

```
$(".row .more").click( 
        function()
        {
            var parentTag = $(this);
            var parentTag = "." + $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('class') + "";
            //$(this).prepend(document.createTextNode(parentTag));      
            $(parentTag + " .forum-stats").slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
        }
    );
```

It does now work. :(
I hope you understand my question... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient solution but try this:

```
$(".row #more").click(function() {
        $(this).parents(".row").children(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");    
    }
);
```

That should work, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @tvanfosson it does not appear so.

Comment: Did you use .more or #more, #more selects by name.  Actually, now that I think about it, I'm not sure how it would work with #more since there are no elements named #more.

Comment: I assumed he thought I meant id="more"

Comment: yes i mean you a need an id="more", but as you know it can be anything just make sure your selector and your link id (or class) match! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href=#more]').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.row > div.hidden').slideToggle('slow');
});
```